Is the variance of the mean of a set of possibly dependent random variables less than the average of their respective variances?
Is the variance of the mean of a set of possibly dependent random variables less than or equal to the average of their respective variances?
Mathematically, given random variables $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ that may be dependent:
Let $\bar{X} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ be the mean of these random variables.
Is it true that:
$$\text{Var}(\bar{X}) \leq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \text{Var}(X_i)$$
I know that for independent random variables, we have the following equality:
$$\text{Var}(\bar{X}) = \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n \text{Var}(X_i)$$
Which clearly satisfies the inequality. However, I'm unsure if this holds for dependent variables.
If this inequality is true, is there a proof or intuitive explanation?
If it's not always true, are there conditions under which it holds? What about the following inequality?
$$\text{Var}(\bar{X}) \leq \text{Max}_{i=1}^n \text{Var}(X_i)$$
Any insights, proofs, or counterexamples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Cross post of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4942864/is-the-variance-of-the-mean-of-a-set-of-possibly-dependent-random-variables-less which has four upvoted answers

I’m voting to close this question because it has already been cross-posted and received answers there.

If the $X_i$ are positively correlated, then the variance of the empirical mean is going to be bigger than in the independent case.
If the $X_i$ are negatively correlated, then the variance of the empirical mean is going to be smaller than in the independent case.
And if they are dependent with 0 correlation? Then we have equality.

That looks as if it is addressing  $\text{Var}(\bar{X}) = \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n \text{Var}(X_i)$ rather than $\text{Var}(\bar{X}) \leq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \text{Var}(X_i)$ (which is true, with equality only when $P(X_i-E[X_i]=X_j-E[X_j])=1$ for all $i,j$ i.e. when there is perfect positive correlation and identical variances).
